# CSS: absolute position is not positioning it relative to the div

Tags: css

I am trying to position a dialog box right under a + (plus) sign.

This is the code I am using:

```
<div class="container"><div class="projectsContainer">
<div class="sectionTitle">Projects</div>
<div class="project-items">

<div class="project-item">
    <div class="projectTitle"><a href="#">Product Management Tool</a></div>
    <div class="projectDetails">
        <div class="projectCompletion">
            <div class="projectProgressed"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="projectMore"><img src="/images/add_button_shadow_blue.png">

        <div class="dialogContainer dialogEditProject"><div class="dialog editProjectDialog"><ul><li id="editProject">Edit</li><li id="removeProject">Remove</li></ul></div></div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>

    <div class="projectDescription">
    No description    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div></div>​
```

In `.projectMore` is `.dialogEditProject` that is absolute positioned. When I load the page in the browser is looks like it is not absolute positioned to it.

Here is the code, to see the behavior live: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4P7D/1/)

Comment: Add `position: relative` to the element you want it to be relative to (assuming it is a child element of course)

Comment: @JohnRobinson Beneath the dialog box

Comment: The below answers are all essentially correct. Absolute positioning is relative to the nearest non-static ancestor, which defaults to the document root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this CSS to `.projectMore`:

```
.projectMore {position: relative;}
.dialogEditProject {position: absolute; top: X; left: Y;} /* X and Y relative to .projectmore */
```

### Explanation

When you give an element `relative` position, it becomes the boundary of the `absolute` positioned elements, so that you can use `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` on the `absolute` positioned element with respect to the relatively positioned parent. :)

Comment: why isn't is assumed by default?

Comment: The `position` will be `static` by default.

Comment: Glad that it helped you out! :) And when you give an element `relative` position, it becomes the boundary of the `absolute` positioned elements, so that you can use `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` on the `absolute` positioned element with respect to the relatively positioned parent. :)

Answer (score 2):

Set `position:relative` on the div .projectDetails.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/E4P7D/2/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have

```
position: relative
```

in the projectDetails?

Try to look at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp)